# Von oder aus im quantitativen Gebrauch

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Man sagt

> **einer von euch**

oder

> **Von Gemüse mag ich besonders Möhren**

Aber jedoch wird nicht **von den möglichen Optionen auswählen**, aber

> **Aus den möglichen Optionen auswählen** gesagt.

Könnte jemand diesen Unterschied kurz erläutern. Ich wäre sehr dankbar.

Comment: Wieso sollte "Von den Optionen auswählen" nicht gebraucht werden? Zumindest mit einem Zahlwort als Akkusativobekt klingt es nicht falsch.

Answer (score 1):

Du kannst auch *von* statt *aus* verwenden, allerdings ist die Bedeutung leicht unterschiedlich:

> aus der Gemüseauslage Möhren auswählen

Das ist *auswählen* im Sinne von *darüber sprechen*.

> von der Gemüseauslage Möhren auswählen

Das ist *auswählen* im Sinne von *wegnehmen*.

Es hängt damit zusammen, das ein mit *von* eingeleitetes Adverbial meist die Herkunft des Akkusativobjektes im Sinne von *dort war es zuvor* angibt.

In dem Zusammenhang *einer von euch* ist es ausnahmsweise die Herkunft im Sinne von *gehört zu eurer Gruppe*, weil der Genitiv *einer der euren* ziemlich altmodisch ist. In Ritterromanen sprechen sie so.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Aber im Satz wie '' Von Kleidung nimm am besten etwas warmes mit'' wäre nur von möglich?

Comment: Das muss entweder ***Von der** Kleidung nimm am besten etwas Warmes mit.* oder besser ***An** Kleidung …*, wenn man nicht auf bestimmte Kleidung zeigt. ***Aus der** Kleidung …* kommt nicht in Frage, ***Aus dem Haufen** Kleidung …* ist jedoch wieder möglich. Tut mir leid, dass es so kompliziert ist.

Comment: Ganz generell ist es im Deutschen immer wichtig, zwischen bestimmten und unbestimmten Dingen und Mengen zu unterscheiden.